# Exception not being caught in c#

Tags: c#

I have the following code and my code does not catch the exception.

In my code I am trying to read all the files for which the access is granted.

```
    var pathsToSearch = new Queue<string>();
    var foundFiles = new List<string>();

    pathsToSearch.Enqueue(startFolder);

    while (pathsToSearch.Count > 0) {
        var dir = pathsToSearch.Dequeue();

        try {
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(dir)) {
                foundFiles.Add(file);
            }

            foreach (var subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(dir)) {
                pathsToSearch.Enqueue(subDir);
            }

        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```

Why does the try catch not work properly or is there some mistake in my code ?

Comment: This is vague, are there exceptions to catch?, what is it dong instead of catching them. is it throwing more other exceptions, does your program crash

Comment: May be you may be getting a different exception, or none. Try changing UnauthorizedAccessException  to Exeception and see if you get any exception.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also keep in mind what external dependencies the operation of your program has!

Comment: var files = Directory.GetFiles(dir); Code breaks at this line throwing UnauthorizedAccessException occured. 
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Access to the path 'E:\System Volume Information' is denied.

Comment: are you sure about type of exception (`UnauthorizedAccessException`) you are getting? and also are you sure about the line where you are getting exception. Is it in your try block? If you are sure about both. you should be able to catch an exception. You can do one thing to be more sure.. add another catch block after your catch block with general type. just add `catch (Exception ex) { }` . see break-point hits there or not.

Comment: Perhaps you're running your program from Visual Studio, which catches First Chance Exceptions by default.  You can turn off this option in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes I am very sure about it and I tried what u said even then the exception hits the same line ! @Amit

Comment: Thanks for the information @jdigital. could you please explain how to turn off that option in Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're running your program from Visual Studio, which catches First Chance Exceptions by default. You can turn off this option in Visual Studio.  I believe this is under Debug > Exceptions, but you may also be able to disable this from the popup dialog that displays the exception.

Here's a Microsoft article that might be helpful: [Understanding Exceptions while debugging with Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/01/07/understanding-exceptions-while-debugging-with-visual-studio/)